# swift uploadTaskWithRequest with didReceiveData

Tags: swift, http, post

I am pretty new to swift i have the following code

```
    var data : AnyObject


    let dict = jsonObject as NSDictionary
    do
    {
        data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options:.PrettyPrinted)

        let strData = NSString(data: data as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

        data = strData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!


        let task = defaultSession.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data as? NSData,
            completionHandler:
            {(data,response,error) in

                guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil
                else {
                    return
                }

    });

    task.resume()

}catch{

    return resultJson
}
```

the resultJson object returns a empty array as there are more date to be downloaded and it takes time.I am wondering weather i can use didReceiveData option to return data after it is downloaded. I searched for code online but couldn't find any. Any help with code is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that the return will run before the upload is finished, and therefore you won't get the desired result. I assume this code is in a function. You need to change it to take a closure as a parameter. Then when the upload is finished, you call that closure. Something like:

```
func doTheUpload(completion completionHandler: ((AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    var data : AnyObject
    let dict = jsonObject as NSDictionary
    do
    {
        data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options:.PrettyPrinted)
        let strData = NSString(data: data as! NSData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        data = strData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let task = defaultSession.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: data as? NSData,
            completionHandler:
            {(data,response,error) in
                guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil
                    completionhandler(resultJson)
                else {
                    return
                }
        });
        task.resume()
    }catch{
        // Do something for error
    }
}
```

Then you would call it as:

```
doTheUpload(completion: {
    resultJson in
    // use the result
})
```

Note that I don't know where you're getting `resultJson` from or what type it is, so you will have to make some changes.